# Django Multiple Databases and login

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to create a Django application with multiple databases. One database for each client. Each client with it's own users Now as far as i can see this is fairly easy to setup:

I defined a middleware to look at the url and set a thread.local variable:

```
my_local_global = local()

class AccountDatabaseMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        database_name = self.get_database_name_from_request(request)
        my_local_global.database_name = database_name

    def get_database_name_from_request(self, request):

       hostname = remove_www(request.get_host().split(':')[0])

       if hostname == '127.0.0.1':
           return 'default'

       database_name = hostname.split('.')[0]
       return database_name
```

and a router that points at the given db:

```
class PartitionRouter(object):

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    from myapp.middleware import my_local_global
    try:
        return my_local_global.database_name
    except AttributeError:
        return 'default'


def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    from babeldat.middleware import my_local_global
    try:
        return my_local_global.database_name
    except AttributeError:
        return 'default'
```

My question is really the following, *is* it that simple? or am i missing something and is this not the way to go and will i run into all kinds of problems (like every database having a django_sessions table, and django_contenttypes etc)...

Comment: Have you considered deploing your application for each client? Instead of using django's middleware to select the database you would have multiple vhosts configured with it's own DB.

Comment: Yes, that would be another possibility. I am trying to weigh the pros and cons of every setup. One being this one application with multiple databases, one being multiple django instances on a single host. One being seperate deployments alltogether. This last one would be an option for larger clients (own dedicated hardware)....